# Indirection and Increment Operator evaluvation

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int op9=9;
    int op99=99;
    int op999=999;
    int op9999=9999;

    int *ptr1=&op9,*ptr2=&op99,*ptr3=&op999,*ptr4=&op9999;

    *ptr1++;
    ++*ptr2;
    (*ptr3)++;
    *++ptr4;

    printf("%d=ptr1 \t %d=ptr2 \t %d=ptr3 \t %d=ptr4",ptr1,ptr2,ptr3,ptr4);

    printf("\n %d = *ptr++ \n %d = ++*ptr \n %d = (*ptr)++ \n %d = *++ptr",*ptr1,*ptr2,*ptr3,*ptr4);

    printf("\n \n  %d=ptr1 \t %d=ptr2 \t %d=ptr3 \t %d=ptr4",ptr1,ptr2,ptr3,ptr4);

    return 0;
}
```

**This is the Output I get**

```
-

    209002336=ptr1   -209002344=ptr2     -209002348=ptr3     -209002348=ptr4

-209002348 = *ptr++ 
     100 = ++*ptr 
     1000 = (*ptr)++ 
     1000 = *++ptr4

      -209002336=ptr1    -209002344=ptr2     -209002348=ptr3     -209002348=ptr4
```

**Why does *ptr++ which is a ptr1 point to ptr3's Address?
and why does *++ptr4 have a value 1000 which is ptr3's value?**

I thought *ptr1++ will point to the next address and since its not part of my program I expected the program to crash. Similarly *++ptr4 should also do the same because its evaluated as *(++ptr4).

So how exactly does Increment and Indirection Operator work for *ptr++ and *++ptr?

Comment: Totally absurd question,one can't get to know about memory placement of several distinct pointers unless they are array,etc. Not suitable for this case,what you are seeing is not at all C related!!!

Comment: Also,to print pointers,we use `%u` format specifier!

Comment: @shekharsuman: `%p` is for printing pointers, usually in hex. `%u` is for unsigned ints whose size may mot match a pointer's size. (You might get away with `%zu`, though.)

Comment: @MOehm-Ahh,I agree! I missed because I have the habit of using `%u` which obviously might be inappropriate any time! THANKS...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explaining the `1000 = *++ptr4`:**

Formally, this is undefined behavior.

Practically, the local variables are allocated in the stack consecutively and in reversed order:

```
int op9;    // SP+3
int op99;   // SP+2
int op999;  // SP+1
int op9999; // SP+0
```

So by taking a pointer to `op9999` and incrementing it, it ends up pointing to `op999`.

Keep in mind that it is still undefined behavior according to the C-language standard.

This effectively means that you may get different results when using different compilers.

Comment: Thank you that makes total sense.

Comment: @Abi: You're welcome, feel free to accept the answer by clicking on the V next to it :)

Answer (score 1):

You asked:

> Why does `*ptr++` which is a `ptr1` point to `ptr3`'s Address?

First of all,

```
*ptr++;
```

is the same as

```
 *(ptr++)
```

The side effect the expression is that `ptr` is incremented, the pointer is dereferenced, and the dereferenced value is discarded. Dereferencing `ptr` after it is incremented is itself cause for undefined behavior. Anything you get after that is potentially unreliable.

As to why `ptr` points to `ptr3`'s address, I am not sure why you think that. Your output doesn't seem to indicate that.

You also asked,

> and why does `*++ptr4` have a value 1000 which is `ptr3`'s value?

The expression `*++ptr4` suffers from the same problem. You are incrementing `ptr4`, and dereferencing the incremented pointer. What you get from dereferencing that pointer is cause for undefined behavior, and hence, unpredictable.

Depending on how your stack is organized, it's quite possible that `ptr4` points to the same address as `ptr3` after it is incremented. However, don't count on such coincident behavior.

Comment: So basically its a compiler dependent issue. The problem was the fact every time I compiled it, I got the same type of issue.
Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Abi, yes, it is a compiler dependent issue. It can also change when you use different optimization levels.

Answer (score 0):

The relative memory order of the `int`s in your code is undefined. Use an array to put them next to each other, in increasing order:

```
int op[] = {9, 99, 999, 9999};
int *ptr1 = &op[0], *ptr2 = &op[1], *ptr3 = &op[2], *ptr4 = &op[3];
```

To print pointers, use the `%p` format specifier.